# Weird stuff happen in all material icon everywhere on my browser

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser, material-design

I have a weird problem. Every time I go to a website who have the material icon I got the name of the icon, not the images. It's hard now when I use material to know which icon to use if I can't see what they look. The thing it's for my own app that working but other app this is what I got.

Do I need to reinstall Chrome ? My version is 53.0.2785.143

This one is https://developers.google.com/web/progressive-web-apps/

[image]

This one is https://design.google.com/icons/

[image]

This is Firebase look at the top right in the search.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Check what happened to the font in the dev tools

Comment: @SLaks I have new picture. Do that help ?

Comment: @SLaks I push an answer hope that can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I remove Material-Icons from my local fonts in my mac and now after a page refresh all work.